# Is it possible to create a one-line constructor with no body that uses an overload in C#

Tags: c#, constructor, overloading

I'm just wondering if its possible to create a one-line constructor without a body in C#, via the use of overloads. For example:

```
//Creates a Wallet instance with the provided cash
public Wallet(int cash)
{
    Cash = cash;
}

//Creates a Wallet instance with no cash
public Wallet() : this(0)
```

At the moment, this doesn't compile, since the second constructor has no body. Is there any way to bypass this, or should i just include an empty body?

Comment: You're missing brackets. `public Wallet() : this(0) { }`

Comment: You should mention that `Wallet` is a `class`, not a `struct`. It makes a difference for zero-parameter non-static constructors.

Answer (score 2):

No.  It's not possible. You have to add a body, although it can be empty and on the same line.